# What is the best way to Handle the Sort Direction in repeater custom paging

Tags: asp.net, sorting, pagination, repeater

I have a repeater with three columns

city, state, zip

```
<table>
<asp:repeater id="rpt" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkCity" runat="server" CommandArgment="City">Name</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
<td>
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkState" runat="server" CommandArgment="State">State</asp:LinkButton></td>
<td><asp:LinkButton id="lnkZip" runat="server" CommandArgment="Name">Zip</asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%# Eval("City") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("State") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Zip") %></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
</table>
```

what is the best way to handle the sort direction for the respective column

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Examples

Comment: i don't wana use any jquery plugin

Comment: then u want to short at sever side ?

Comment: yes i want to sort at server side

Comment: then put ur .cs file code for databind